# I installed a navigation bar with external css and it affected the rest of the website links

Tags: css, class, html, stylesheet

I created an external style sheet and installed a navigation bar at the top of my index page. The two links on the bottom of the page were affected. I then added css code for those links. They are now invisible, although they still work.

**Update: Solved** by using the first three answers on the following stackoverflow post:

[My Navigation Bar CSS is overwriting my other links CSS on Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925818/my-navigation-bar-css-is-overwriting-my-other-links-css-on-opera)

(I have left my original incorrect code intact.)

Moderators feel free to edit or delete my post if linking an answer is against site guidelines or if this question is considered redundant.

```
/* regular links */

a.normal:link{
  color:#0000FF;
}
a.normal:visited{
color:#800080;
}
a.normal:active{
color:#FF0000;
}

/* navigation bar links */

ul.nav{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  padding-top:6px;
  padding-bottom:6px;
}
ul.nav li{
  display:inline;
}
ul.nav a:link,a:visited{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#56A5EC;
  text-align:center;
  padding:6px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
ul.nav a:hover,a:active{
  background-color:#488AC7;
}
```

Navigation bar:

```
</p>
<br>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="http://www.mysite.com">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="inventory.htm">In Stock</a></li>
  <li><a href="order.htm">Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="faq.htm">faq</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<p>
```

Normal links:

```
</p>
<class="normal">
Start here <a href="pictures.htm">Pictures</a><br>
More items <a href="more-examples.htm">More examples</a><br>    
</class>
<p>
```

Comment: A vague question with no actual code or reference.  How you expecting people to help you exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If the external stylesheet is affecting undesired links, then you aren't explicitly specifying your top navigation links.

See the three links below for more information on CSS specificity:

- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
- http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-understanding-css-specificity/

**Please provide all relevant code if you need an exact answer and code revision.** It's currently impossible to help you with the little amount of information you've provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for sending the links.

Comment: Not a problem, hope it helps. If this resolved your issue, please make sure to mark it as an answer.